# how to retrieves scores for more than one grade event on one instance

Tags: mysql

I have a score table that keep track of my students score. the score table has 3 fields(gradeEventId,Score,StudentId). The problem is that i have been looking for a way to retrieve all the score associated with each student per gradeEvent in one query and display it all on one page.
The query that i have been using

```
$sql = "
SELECT
student.id, name, UNIX_TIMESTAMP (gradeEvent.EventDate) as eventDate,
score.score AS score, gradeEvent.subjectId
FROM student_table
INNER JOIN gradeEvent_table
RIGHT JOIN classLevel_table ON classLevel.classId = student.classId
LEFT JOIN score_table ON student.id = score.student.id
AND gradeEvent.eventId = score.gradeEventId
WHERE gradeEvent.eventId = $gradeEvent
AND student.classId = $class_id
```

only retrieves scores from a single grade event.
is it possible to retrieve scores for more than one grade event? please assist

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `=` you could use `IN`:

```
WHERE gradeEvent.eventId IN (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The `?` are parameters for various `$gradeEvent`s